How To Make A Field Invisible In An Inherited Odoo View When The Field Is Defined In A Parent View?
I'm working on an Odoo module and need to make an existing field (sale_line_id) invisible in a form view. This field is defined in a parent view, and my custom view inherits from it. Despite my attempts, the field remains visible in the form view. Here is what I have done so far:
Inheriting the Parent View: I ensured that I'm inheriting the correct parent view.
Using XPath Expression: I'm using an XPath expression to locate the sale_line_id field and set it to invisible.
Here is the XML code snippet I'm using:
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_task_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.task.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">project.task</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_line_id']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>


Despite this, the sale_line_id field is still visible in the form view.
And always facing this error
**Element '' cannot be located in parent view
**

You have targeted a field added to the sale_project module, so you need to add it to your module's dependencies.

still the same error, and the same thing with the create form in kanban view i couldn't target the field to add a domain

it's like m not writing any code the field still apear in the view ...
